# how to make column width responsive to content Jsgrid

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

I am [JSGrid](http://js-grid.com) to show data in a grid. however jsgrid column is not adjusting to the values. I don't want the fixed width of columns and if i dont give width the data overflow the next column as shown
[image: tbale with no width mentioned].

i found work around solution mentioned here [auto adjust columns](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/450)

```
 .jsgrid-header-cell,
    .jsgrid-cell {
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
```

[image: after applying mentioned css]

but the problem is i dont want to hide the overflow data in the header and somehow wrap the values in data columns . any solution or workaround

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to do anything, just set **width: "100%"** in your datagrid and the **width** in the columns you should use the minimum value you want, using the minimum value jsgrid will do the horizontal scroll automaticly.
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poGcm.png)